# sleep/wait function in velocity

Tags: velocity

Using apache velocity, I am performing a SNMP poll to a network device for Received packets. The aim is to get the Received packets per sec (PPS) but the network device only returns cumulative value.

So my plan was to run the snmp poll every sec and I can subtract the old valued from the new value to get PPS.

I could not find any sleep or wait function in apache velocity that can delay the poll by one sec.

Below is my script for reference.

```
#device($defensePro, 'type=defensePro', 'lazyConnect=true')
#param($output, 'type=string', 'direction=out')
#set($dp = $defensePro.readAllBeans('RsACCStatEntry'))
#result('text/text')
#foreach($x in $dp)
  #if($x.id.toString().equals('RECEIVED'))
    #set($id = $x.id)
    #set($value = $x.value)
    $date.get('H:m:s') Poll $velocityCount: $id $value
  #end      
#end   
#end
```

Output

```
18:33:53 Poll 1: RECEIVED 18878707
```

Can someone please let me know if there is a sleep function in apache velocity or any other way of achieving the desired result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it the right way, but Velocity can call [java methods](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#methods)

Add method (to your defensePro for example) as

`public void sleep() { Thread.sleep(1000) }`

And call it from template

```
$defensePro.sleep();
```

Found a very old answer in [velocity mailing list](https://markmail.org/message/zl4qxpd2ckzqykhw)

> Thread.sleep should work. It pauses the current Thread for the given
>   amount of time

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, below worked for me

```
#device($defensePro, 'type=defensePro', 'lazyConnect=true')
#param($output, 'type=string', 'direction=out')
#set($dp = $defensePro.readAllBeans('RsACCStatEntry'))
    #macro(sleepX, $seconds)
    #set($duration = $seconds * 1000)
    #set($class = $class.inspect('java.lang.Thread'))
    $class.type.sleep($duration)
    #end
#foreach($i in [1..6])
#foreach($x in $dp)
#if($x.id.toString().equals('RECEIVED'))
#set($id = $x.id)
#set($value = $x.value)
$date.get('H:m:s') Poll $i: $id $value
#sleepX(1)
#end    #end   #end
```

Sample Output

```
17:4:10 Poll 1: RECEIVED 0
17:4:12 Poll 2: RECEIVED 0
17:4:13 Poll 3: RECEIVED 0
17:4:14 Poll 4: RECEIVED 0
17:4:15 Poll 5: RECEIVED 0
17:4:16 Poll 6: RECEIVED 0
```